# Display date 30 days from now having only the 30th day detect if its a weekend or holiday for correct day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will exclude weekends and holidays. I am trying to display in a text box 30 days from today. Once the 30 days loops check that day and make sure it is not a holiday if it is select the next available day. For some reason the one I have come up with includes all holidays that it is looping through so it is giving me a date of 12/21 as of today. When the end result I am looking for is 12/04. Will someone please tell me how to adjust this accordingly?

http://jsfiddle.net/byyeh83t/9/

Also for example if today was 10/12/2015 30 days from now is 11/11/2015 which is veterans day this function should know that this day is a holiday and then make it 11/12/2015 not ever allowing it to be on a weekend either. No weekends no holidays listed
http://jsfiddle.net/byyeh83t/13/

**HTML**

```
<input name="workExemptDays" id="workExemptDays" type="text"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Testing purposes
    var natDays = [
        [2014, 1, 1, 'New Year'], 
        [2014, 1, 20, 'Martin Luther King'], 
        [2014, 2, 17, 'Washingtons Birthday'],       
        [2014, 5, 26, 'Memorial Day'], 
        [2014, 7, 4, 'Independence Day'], 
        [2014, 9, 1, 'Labour Day'], 
        [2014, 10, 13, 'Columbus Day'], 
        [2014, 11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], 
        [2014, 11, 27, 'Thanksgiving Day'], 
        [2014, 11, 28, 'Thanksgiving Day'],
        [2014, 12, 25, 'Christmas'],  
        [2014, 12, 26, 'Christmas'], 
        [2015, 1, 1, 'New Year'], 
        [2015, 1, 19, 'Martin Luther King'], 
        [2015, 2, 16, 'Washingtons Birthday'],       
        [2015, 5, 25, 'Memorial Day'], 
        [2015, 7, 3, 'Independence Day'], 
        [2015, 9, 7, 'Labour Day'], 
        [2015, 10, 12, 'Columbus Day'], 
        [2015, 11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], 
        [2015, 11, 26, 'Thanksgiving Day'], 
        [2015, 11, 27, 'Thanksgiving Day'],
        [2015, 12, 24, 'Christmas'],  
        [2015, 12, 25, 'Christmas']  
        ];


// dateMin is the minimum delivery date
var dateMin = new Date();


function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
    var date = new Date(curdate.getTime());
    while (weekDaysToAdd > 0) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        //check if current day is business day
        if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(date)[0]) {
            weekDaysToAdd--;
        }
    }
    return date;
}


function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return (noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend);
}


function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() == natDays[i][0] && date.getMonth() == natDays[i][1] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][2]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][3] + '_day'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}


function setDeliveryDate(date) {
    $('#workExemptDays').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date));
}


setDeliveryDate(AddBusinessDays(dateMin, 30));

});
```

Basically how do display date 30 days from now having only the 30th day detect if its a weekend or holiday to make sure it is a valid day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are checking every day from now to the next 30 days to see if each is a weekend or holiday. if one is a weekend or holiday you are removing a day. so basically you are adding 30 business working days.

To get the first non weekend or holiday after 30 days, what you need to do is add the 30 days to start with, then check from that date and keep incrementing by 1 until you find a day not a weekend or holiday.

change `AddBusinessDays` function to something like this:-

```
function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
    var date = new Date((new Date()).setDate(curdate.getDate() + weekDaysToAdd));
    while (!noWeekendsOrHolidays(date)) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return date;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/byyeh83t/14/)